# How to convert clonezilla backup image to virtual machine?

Tags: virtualization, virtual-machines, virtualbox, physical-to-virtual, clonezilla

I have a 30gB tar.gz disk image of a physical debian machine, created by clonezilla - what's the easiest list of steps to follow to convert it to a virtual machine?
Do i have to necessarily make .iso? I ran into trouble making a big .iso like that with genisoimage.

Comment: You perform a restore just like you would with real hardware.  Boot up with the clonezilla image (the boot image from clonezilla, not the image you took) on your VM and go through the restore procedures.  This is what clonezilla is designed for.

Answer (score 5):

Here are the steps:

- Create New Virtual Machine and boot from clonezilla ISO image of CD.
- Restore clonezilla image like normal procedure.

Comment: I used clonezilla to backup a disk, but the output is not an ISO.

Comment: You had to boot into Clonezilla from a USB or CD.  The image used to create that physical media is what you use in the VM to boot up.  Once booted up in Clonezilla in your VM, just restore the backup into the VM.

Comment: I did boot from a USB, but the result is not an ISO - it's a folder full of files, the biggest one has .gz extension (NOT iso)

Comment: This does not work in 99/100 cases. The biggest hurdle is disk sizes. The first part of a decent answer here should be how to create a VHD that is the same size as the drive the image was made from.